# Gluon TS. Next day forecast error and question

Tags: time-series, gluon, amazon-forecast

Good day!

I am trying to forecast for 1 day into the future with Gluon TS.

My dataset looks like this:

df:
Date Volume
Jan1 100 ...
June1 99
June2 105
June3 90
June4 NaN

How do I forecast 1 day into the future (June4)?

I have tried the following as an example:

```
test_data = ListDataset([{"start": df.index[0], 
                              "target": df.Volume[:"June4"]}], 
                            freq="D")

    estimator = NBEATSEstimator(freq="D", prediction_length=1, context_length = 5,trainer=Trainer(epochs=60,ctx="gpu"))
    predictor = estimator.train(training_data=test_data)
```

**_However, I get an error: 'Got NaN in first epoch. Try reducing initial learning rate.'__**

**What should I do to forecast June4 if I have all previous data available (June3 and earlier)? What am I doing wrong?**

Also, If I use target June3 instead (same dataset as above with data including June3 and June4 NaN value).

```
test_data = ListDataset([{"start": df.index[0], 
                            "target": df.Volume[:"June3"]}], 
                          freq="D")

  estimator = NBEATSEstimator(freq="D", prediction_length=1, context_length = 5,trainer=Trainer(epochs=60,ctx="gpu"))
  predictor = estimator.train(training_data=test_data)
```

Forecasting results that I am getting are super close to June3 results.

**Does it simply replicates June3 results, or does it use June2 and earlier and then tries to predict 1 day into the future (June3)?**